# Is there a way to ensure that an iOS IPA was built with the same code last checked into a git repo

Tags: git, xamarin, continuous-integration, atlassian-sourcetree, ipa

Is there a way to ensure that an iOS IPA was built with the same code last checked into the git repo.

Using SourceTree on a xamarin app

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new IPA with the last checked in code base and it to your existing IPA.

Comment: Good idea but how could I compare the 2 IPAs to see if they are different and even better see where they differ. I want to ensure there were no last minutes changes before the build. Would a CRC check work just not sure

Comment: @StackMan Yea I was thinking a CRC check would do it, but I do not know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a Jenkins job that will clone your repository, build your application and on a successful build, commit to the repository an update to the number version of your app.

[Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/)